# How can I get Twitter hashtags to pull from a custom field on WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, twitter

I'm trying to get custom fields to pull up a hashtag I put in inside a tweet button.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="artofbackpackin" data-related="artofbackpackin" data-hashtags="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "tweethashtag", true); ?>">Tweet</a>
```

I've got the custom field filled in but for whatever reason, the hashtag is not displaying on the tweet button.

Has anyone tried doing this before?

Sorry. I should have added more details. The code above and the javascript is from the official Twitter share buttons.
https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet

The javascript is this:
    < script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");< /script>

If I were to put in normal text for data-related, it reads it okay and adds the hashtag to the tweet. Just not with the custom field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the "Tweet" text to your post meta:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="artofbackpackin" data-related="artofbackpackin" data-hashtags="<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "tweethashtag", true); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, "tweethashtag", true); ?></a>
```

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything. Does it work on your side? Although I'm confused how changing the "Tweet" would include the hashtag I decide to put inside the data-hashtag part of the tweet.

Comment: It means the "tweethashtag" is empty for the current post. Could you check it first?

Comment: Yeap. tweethashtag is definitely filled in for a custom field.

Comment: Try to use get_the_ID instead of $post->ID